# Detecting document contours from camera preview

Tags: android, opencv

I am building a document scanner app that simply takes pictures and uploads it through an api. Now I would like to add contour detection on the live preview of the camera. I have already achieved this through openCV(here is a question I had already [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39008380/detecting-the-largest-contour-with-opencv)). This issue with openCV is that I would have to either do a static import of the manager which is a very big library and it increases the app size or make the user download openCV manager. Is there any library that will achieve contour detection without bloating the app or making the user download another app ?